# Grouping objects to list using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I'm having problems because my select is returning several lines of result due to an Options object that has several different options, and I needed to group this result in java.

**I have the parent class which is the QuestionEventDTO:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QuestionEventDTO {
    
    public Long id;
    public QuestionDTO question;
    public List<QuestionDTO> questions;

}
```

**And I have the daughter class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QuestionDTO {
    
    public Long id;
    public OptionDTO option;
    public List<OptionDTO> options;

}
```

**And I have the granddaughter class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OptionDTO {
    
    public Long id;
    public String description;

}
```

**After hitting the procedure, I set the response fields:**

```
public class QuestionEventMapper implements RowMapper<QuestionEventDTO> {

    @Override
    public QuestionEventDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        QuestionEventDTO dto = new QuestionEventDTO();
        dto.setId(rs.getLong(1));
        dto.setQuestion(new QuestionDTO(rs.getLong(2), new QuestionOptionDTO(rs.getLong(3), rs.getString(4)), null));
        
        return dto;
    }

}
```

```
QuestionEventDTO [id=1, question= QuestionDTO [id=1, option= OptionDTO [id=1, description="Are you Dev?"], options = []], questions =[]]
QuestionEventDTO [id=1, question= QuestionDTO [id=1, option= OptionDTO [id=2, description="What's rating?"], options = []], questions =[]]
QuestionEventDTO [id=2, question= QuestionDTO [id=2, option= OptionDTO [id=3, description="What's your dog's name?"], options = []], questions =[]]
QuestionEventDTO [id=2, question= QuestionDTO [id=2, option= OptionDTO [id=4, description="Are you Dev?"], options = []], questions =[]]
```

**But I would like it to stay like this:**

```
QuestionEventDTO [id=1, question= null, questions = QuestionDTO [id=1, option= null, options = [OptionDTO [id=1, description="Are you Dev?"], OptionDTO [id=2, description="What's rating?"]]]]
QuestionEventDTO [id=2, question= null, questions = QuestionDTO [id=2, option= null, options = [OptionDTO [id=3, description="What's your dog's name?"], OptionDTO [id=4, description="Are you Dev?"]]]]
```

I don't have much experience in lambda, I would like a solution to this problem, could someone help me?

Comment: Don't force yourself to write lambda, just use normal code with for loop and we can convert to lambda later.

Comment: @huy So I tried to do it without lambda, but it didn't work...

Comment: i don't see your code to convert from select to expected data.

Comment: How does your select look like?

Comment: it's a procedure that I perform, and when I set the values, I set the way I'm going to post in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try.

> **WARNING** | Beware that this is only a POC and not good readable code.

What you need is a method, that takes a `List<QuestionEventDTO>` and transforms it to another `List<QuestionEventDTO>`.

It is possible to do it with streams and nested streams in the map-methods.

Here is the steps this streams will take:

---

1. Group the `QuestionDTO` by the ID of the `QuestionEventDTO`'s

   - Input: `List<QuestionEventDTO>`
   - Output: `Map<Long, List<QuestionEventDTO>>`
2. Transform the grouped Lists to `Map<Long, List<QuestionDTO>`

   - Input: `Map<Long, List<QuestionEventDTO>>`
   - Output: `Map<Long, Map<Long, List<QuestionDTO>>>`
3. Transform the grouped `QuestionDTO` to a `Map<Long, OptionDTO>`

   - Input: `Map<Long, Map<Long, List<QuestionDTO>>>`
   - Output: `Map<Long, Map<Long, Map<Long, OptionDTO>>>`

---

4. Transform the grouped objects to new `QuestionEventDTO` where the Lists are filled.

---

Here is what the code would look like (heavy usage of `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.toMap`):

```java
private static List<QuestionEventDTO> transform(List<QuestionEventDTO> events) {
  //Step1
  Map<Long, List<QuestionEventDTO>> groupedByQuestionEventId = events.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(QuestionEventDTO::getId));
  
  //Step 2
  Map<Long, Map<Long, List<QuestionDTO>>> alsoGroupedQuestionID = groupedByQuestionEventId
      .entrySet().stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
          e -> e.getValue().stream()
              .map(v -> v.getQuestion())
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(QuestionDTO::getId)))
      );

  //Step 3
  Map<Long, Map<Long, Map<Long, OptionDTO>>> alsoGroupedByOptionID = alsoGroupedQuestionID
      .entrySet().stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
          e -> e.getValue()
              .entrySet().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                  v -> v.getValue().stream()
                      .map(QuestionDTO::getOption)
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(OptionDTO::getId, t -> t))))));

  //Step 4
  List<QuestionEventDTO> transformedBack = alsoGroupedByOptionID.entrySet().stream()
      .map(e -> {
        QuestionEventDTO eventDTO = new QuestionEventDTO();
        eventDTO.setId(e.getKey());

        List<QuestionDTO> questions = e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .map(q -> {
              QuestionDTO questionDTO = new QuestionDTO();
              questionDTO.setId(q.getKey());
              questionDTO.setOptions(new ArrayList<>(q.getValue().values()));
              return questionDTO;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        eventDTO.setQuestions(questions);
        return eventDTO;
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

  return transformedBack;
}
```

Of course you don't need the variables for each step and you also could combine step 2 and 3. Then the code would look like this (not very readable):

```java
private static List<QuestionEventDTO> transformShorter(List<QuestionEventDTO> events) {
  return events.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(QuestionEventDTO::getId))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
          e -> e.getValue().stream()
              .map(QuestionEventDTO::getQuestion)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(QuestionDTO::getId))
              .entrySet().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                  q -> q.getValue().stream()
                      .map(QuestionDTO::getOption)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList()))))
      )
      .entrySet().stream()
      .map(e -> {
        QuestionEventDTO eventDTO = new QuestionEventDTO();
        eventDTO.setId(e.getKey());

        List<QuestionDTO> questions = e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .map(q -> {
              QuestionDTO questionDTO = new QuestionDTO();
              questionDTO.setId(q.getKey());
              questionDTO.setOptions(q.getValue());
              return questionDTO;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        eventDTO.setQuestions(questions);
        return eventDTO;
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```